# How to add an external URL on Action Sheet button

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have controller like this

```
   var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
     buttons: [
       { text: 'Bet '+'on '+'<b>'+bookerName+'</b>'},
       { text: 'Bet with coins (12)' }
     ],
     titleText: 'How you want to bet',
     cancelText: 'Cancel',
     cancel: function() {
          // add cancel code..
        },
     buttonClicked: function(index) {
       if (index === 0) {
       console.log("button1");
       } else if (index === 1) {
       console.log("button2");
       }
     }
   });
```

Action sheet works fine. But how can I add external URL on click to button, how can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? redirect to the external URL?

Comment: I know it's sounds simple, but I'm stuck on this, please help.